# Помогите доделать индикатор на Lua

Tags: lua

```
Settings = {
    Name = "HLOC",
    line = {
    {
        Name = "HI",
        Color = RGB(0, 0, 255),
        Type = POINT_LINE,
        Width = 1
    },
    {
        Name = "LOW",
        Color = RGB(255, 0, 0),
        Type = POINT_LINE,
        Width = 1
    },
    {
        Name = "Open",
        Color = RGB(0, 255, 0),
        Type = POINT_LINE,
        Width = 1
    },
    {
        Name = "Close",
        Color = RGB(255, 255, 0),
        Type = POINT_LINE,
        Width = 1
    }
  }
}

function Init() 
    return 4
end

function OnCalculate(index)
    local High, Low, Open, Close
    local year, month, day, hour, week_day

    --максимум свечей в 1-м графике 1440 свечей. на самом деле меньше. но сделаем 1450
    local max_candle = Size()

    -- получение таймфрейма текущего графика
    c_year = T(index).year
    c_month = T(index).month
    c_day = T(index).day
    --week_day = T(index).week_day

    p_year = nil
    p_month = nil
    p_day = nil

    High = 0
    Low = 0 
    Open = 0 
    Close = 0

    -- получаем дату предыдущего дн¤

    for i = 1, max_candle - index - 1 do

        -- пропускаем свечи текущего дн¤
        if (c_year == T(index-i).year) and (c_month == T(index-i).month) and (c_day == T(index-i).day) then
            -- свечка еще в текущем дне
        else
        --получили свечку предыдущего периода
            if p_year == nil then --предыдущий период не определен
                p_year = T(index-i).year
                p_month = T(index-i).month
                p_day = T(index-i).day
                --последн¤¤ свечека периода. по ней получаем Close периода
                Close = C(index-i)
                High = H(index-i)
                Low = L(index-i)
            elseif (p_year == T(index-i).year) and (p_month == T(index-i).month) and (p_day == T(index-i).day) then --предыдущий период определен и попадает в день периода отбора, получаем hi - low
                -- получаем Hi Low периода
                if not (H(index-i) < High)  then
                    High = H(index-i)
                end             
                if (L(index-i) < Low) or (Low == 0)then
                    Low = L(index-i)
                end
            else --свечка выходит за период текущего дн¤ и определенного периода
                --последн¤¤ свечка предыдущего периода от нужного. по +1 получаем первую свечку нужного периода и его Open
                Open = O(index-i+1)
                break
            end
        end         
    end  

    return High, Low, Open, Close
end
```

Comment: опишите в вопросе какую задачу вы решаете и что конкретно вызывает трудности или ошибки